# How to print out diskspace being consumed by a user's home directory with files

Tags: linux, unix, du

How can I print out the amount of diskspace that a particular user is consuming in their home directory with files? I want to print out each file and its size in K and then at the end print out a grand total of diskspace used in K as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Linux & Unix or Ubuntu StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
du -a -k ~/
```

From the `manpage` `man du`,

```
-a, --all
write counts for all files, not just directories
-k
like --block-size=1K
```

The "grand total of diskspace used in K" will automatically be displayed on the last line.

For directories with many items, or to simply speed-up the result and suppress `stdout` output, add a pipe to `tail` to show only the resulting last line, and use optional `-h` flag for `'human-readable'` display:

```
du -h ~/ | tail -n 1
15G /home/david/
```